# How to configure proxy settings in NetBeans 8.2 RC?

Tags: java, plugins, netbeans, proxy

I have an issue with NetBeans, I have been trying to install some plugins to the IDE but it show me an error:

> Unable to connect to the Plugin Portal because of Connection reset

It says I have to check my proxy settings, but I am not using any proxy. I already put this: `-J-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack = true` in the netbeans.conf file, but it doesn't work.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the proxy settings under Tools > Options > General.

But you can consider downloading a newer version of NetBeans, since version 8.2 does not seems maintained anymore (it's pre-Apache).

The latest version as today is 12.4 and you can download at:
https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html

Comment: Yes, what happens is that I marked the option "without proxy" and the error still continues. There are another solution for the error?

Comment: Did you think about the version upgrade? As I said, 8.2 is old, and it can be pointing to a plugin portal that is no longer active. In 12.4 you can go to Tools > Plugins > Settings and see what are the servers that it is using. See if you have a similar feature in your 8.2.

Comment: See if this helps: this guy found that changing the settings from 'https' to 'http' worked for him: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2386

Comment: I had already tried that, but it also didn't work, anyway I think using Apache NetBeans 12 it's the best solution.